# Convert a property of maps with comma separated string to Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: spring, spring-3

There is a property file which is structured as below:

```
prob1=a,b,c,d
prob2=e,f,j,h
```

We want to convert it to `Map<String,List<String>>`

I know I can read a map and make a map bean from property files as:

```
<util:properties id="probs"
location="classpath:/configs/sample.properties" />
```

I know that I can convert the list of comma separated string to List with:

```
@Value("#{'${prob1}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> Probs;
```

But I don't know how can I achieve a `Map<String,List<String>>`

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at `Properties.entrySet()` and see where that could lead.

Comment: Can you explain more?! How can I access this method?

Comment: `Properties extends HashTable<Object,Object>` - I'll answer in full below

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a `Map<String,List<String>>` in the first place, i.e. what would that do, that a `Properties` can't achieve?

Otherwise, the quick and dirty approach is something like this:

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
for ( Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry : properties.entrySet() )
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.addAll( Arrays.asList( ((String)entry.getValue()).split( "," ) ) );
    map.put( (String)entry.getKey() , list );
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: By the map<String,List<String>> I can find map.get("proper1").contains("a"). I think I can not achieve it with Properties
By the way how can I use your code so that the Spring makes this bean for me. Should I write a bean to convert myself or can I do it with less code!